# Contar elementos de un array en javascript

Tags: javascript, php, array

Tengo un response que me llega desde el server, vienen 2 grupos de elemento separados por comas, pero al hacer un length en javascript no cuenta los 2 grupos de elementos sino que me dice que hay 167 lo cual es falso.

respuesta desde el server

```
[{"num":0,"id_banco":"1","documento":"23829135","monto":"12.4","fecha":"2022-03-15"},{"num":1,"id_banco":"3","documento":"43766620","monto":"22","fecha":"2022-03-15"}]
```

codigo de javascript

```
success: function(response){
                    let len = response.length;
                    console.log(len); //Me responde 167
```

Comment: Me acabo de fijar , y a mi me devuelve 2. Tiene que haber algo mas que esta haciendolo fallar. Tenes el codigo en algun lado donde se pueda ver mejor? como codesandbox o git?

Comment: lo que veo es que me cuenta es cada elemento por eso pone que hay 167 y no los 2 grupos de elementos llevo 4 horas en lo mismo y no lo resuelvo

Comment: Te falta el `response.json()`. Ese 167, es la cantidad de letras que tiene el string antes de convertirlo a un objeto de javascript. Antes de hacer nada por favor, agrega `response = response.json()` en la primera línea de tu función `success`.

Comment: Te amo Jaime Menéndez ya esta solucionado :)

Comment: Ojo, no siempre `response = response.json()` como te puse en mi comentario va a funcionar. Dependiendo de la `api` que estés usando `response.json()` puede devolver una promesa o los datos directamente. Otra variante dado que te llega un string es usar `response = JSON.parse(response)` y puede que hasta te sea mejor en tu caso. Para la próxima, especifica la librería con la que realizas las peticiones, y cuida las etiquetas de tu pregunta, esto no tiene que ver con php.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez El código parece ser basado en Ajax (usando jQuery). Si es así, con agregarle un `dataType: 'json'` a la petición, te convertirá la respuesta en JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que no convertiste la respuesta a **JSON** sino que es un **String** y no puedes usarlo como un **Object**.

Puedes resolverlo así:

```js
{
    success: function(response) {
        response = response.json();
            
        var length = response.length;
            
        console.log("Longitud de la respuesta: " + length)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No se pueden crear objetos json con propiedades de diferente tipo
Tampoco cierras correctamente la function que recibe el parámetro response

Prueba con este código:

```
[{"num":"0","id_banco":"1","documento":"23829135","monto":"12.4","fecha":"2022-03-15"},{"num":"1","id_banco":"3","documento":"43766620","monto":"22","fecha":"2022-03-15"}]

success: function(response){
                let len = response.length;
                console.log(len); //Me responde 167
}
```

Comment: En **JSON** se puede usar propiedades de cualquier tipo. Esta respuesta es incorrecta

Comment: Si que se pueden hacer de cualquier tipo, pero, las tienes que escribir bien con las comillas dobles en todas...

Comment: Claramente, si no te dara un ``SyntaxError``